# Require new users to be confirmed by an administrator in MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki

After setting

```
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read']    = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit']    = false; 
$wgEmailConfirmToEdit = true;
```

anonymous users can't edit any page because each time they are asked to confirm their E-mail address.
I want to add one more condition that only administrator can confirm new users. How to do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making registration for media wiki require admin approval?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815321/making-registration-for-media-wiki-require-admin-approval)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anonymous users can't edit pages using the setup you describe because you have specifically disabled their editing permissions by setting: `$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit']    = false;` .

It sounds like what you want to do is create a new group with editing permissions and then have administrators add users to that group when they have confirmed the user instead of using email confirmation.  So for example:

```
$wgEmailConfirmToEdit = false;

$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read']    = true;
$wgGroupPermissions['*']['edit']    = false; 
$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit']    = false;

$wgGroupPermissions['confirmeduser']['edit']    = true;
```

Then an administrator can add users to the confirmeduser group to give them editing permissions.

Comment: `$wgEmailConfirmToEdit = false;` and `$wgGroupPermissions['*']['read'] = true;` are unnecessary (these are the default settings). On the other hand, you will need `$wgGroupPermissions['user']['edit'] = false;` plus some [$wgAddGroups](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgAddGroups) settings. (See [the user rights manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:User_rights) for details.)

Comment: Yeah I put those lines in to contrast his sample configuration. Good call on the user setting.

Comment: Are the $wgAddGroups settings necessary? I thought admins could add all groups by default.

Comment: I think you need to be a bureaucrat for that.